# How to integrate the Jenkins and soap UI using windows batch command

Tags: jenkins, soapui

I need to configure my soap ui project through  jenkins using windows batch command but the soap project is not executing the cases.

Below command line is working from command prompt and running the project but same line is not working in the jenkins (cmd)

```
cd C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin 

testrunner.bat "localprojecpath\soapProjectFile.xml"
```

[image]

In the jenkins it shows loading--->>
but project is not running yet so need some one help on this.

Comment: Hi...WC to SO! Please Follow the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting the questions. Also please don't attach images

Comment: Have you tried the suggested jenkins pipeline: https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/integrations/jenkins.html

Comment: Ready Api is licensed one but I'm currently using open source version

Comment: Have you considered using the Maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are doing is fine. But it seems like you are using some imported JAR files, that hasn't been added to the free version of SoapUI used on your build server.

> > Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Whatever JAR you've included when using this class, should also be added to the SoapUI installations on each and every one of your build servers.

Comment: That is a message fro SLF4J. That is irrelevant to OP's problem.

Comment: It will be very helpful if some one solve this problem